# Scrollbar visible but it won't scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website which uses 100% width and I accidentally removed the scrollbar.

When I coded back in the scrollbar it's visible but will not scroll down the page. I have the CSS code and the script. What other code do I need to get the scrollbar to scroll down the page?

Here is my existing code within my page:

Site link: http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/MXJGTV/Index1.html

Please go to the above address and right click and view source code because I don't know how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the body `position:fixed;`. That property makes it so the body cannot be scrolled. Delete that line and your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inline `position: fixed` in the body tag. Remove it and fix the whole code because it's pretty messy

Comment: Really strange, the position: fixed is causing the scroll problem. Are you sure you removed it? Did you reload the page? Maybe you're looking a t a cached version